# How can I Upgrade Agora SDK in Unity to support WebGL as well as Windows?

Tags: unity-webgl, agora-implementation, agora

I have implemented video and voice calling SDK into Unity and have that all working,
But we want to deploy our 'game' to multiple platforms including WebGL.
I have downloaded the latest WebGL package here:
https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora_Unity_WebGL/releases
But when importing into the project there are 87 Errors..
Is there an easy way to implement WebGL and Windows compatability?

Could anyone help point me in the right direction or give me some documentation to read about this?
Most of the errors mentioned above come from duplicated namespaces etc. so do I need to delete the original Agora SDK and then install the The one from the github link above in order to eliminate duplicate namespaces?
And if I do that, will it work on native platforms as well, or only on WebGL?

I downloaded the .UnityPackage and imported it into Unity.
I got around 87 Errors I think mostly from duplicated namespaces,
But I expected it to simply update the SDK to a version that allows me to create a WebGL build